UML: Association vs operation
I want model something in class diagram. sometime it seems you can use association or just operation. for example User and Product, should they have association with name Add or should class User have operation names addProduct? or should I do both? I have search a lot and tried some Ais but there is no clear answer

A label "Add" should usually not be attached to an association for the described case. Do you have any reference on the web where you found this strange modeling? Or did you just "invent" it for this question?

@DocBrown I don't have exact reference for my example but another example is typical for course and student they usually have association with label enroll, that made me wonder why operation here and why association in that example

Associations in a class diagram are more comparable to attributes of a class than to the methods of a class.
If you have the classes User and Product, an association between those can be that the User owns or subscribes one or more Products.
A class diagram is used to show how the classes relate to each other without focusing on which operations can be done or how that structure is formed at run-time. While you can show which operations a class supports, that is of secondary interest and a class diagram cannot show how different classes/objects interact. For the interaction, there are different types of diagrams.

The use of operations and labels on associations address two different cases.
If your User has an operation addProduct that accepts an instance of Product as an argument, then I'd expect to see all of this captured as an operation on the User class.
Depending on what happens in addProduct, there is likely to be a relationship between User and Product. Minimally, this is a usage dependency. This could be strengthened with association, composition, or aggregation relationships and navigability markers.
Regardless of the relationship, you can also add a label to denote the association end to define the relationship with additional details.
Something to consider would be the mode of use of UML. Using UML as a standardized notation to communicate sketches and notes is very different than using UML as a formal and complete blueprint or specification and the level of details may vary. Based on how UML diagrams or models are being used, stakeholders consuming them may have different needs or expectations for the content.

I get from your answer that it is mandatory to have an operation and depending on what happen in that there may be an association too. I also have to said by label I meant association name

@ali.qb I wouldn't say mandatory, no. If you are using UML as notes or a sketch, you may opt to not show any attributes or operations on a class and instead focus on the relations. This goes to the mode of use of UML. Nothing says that a specific UML diagram or model needs to contain all details of a class or its relationship to other classes - details could be left off of the model, but any details that do appear should be correct.
